# When upload image second time using same name using laravel 5 but showing old image on browser

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.3

Before uploading check if file exists then delete this image and upload new image using laravel functionality but showing first uploaded image when hitting image url on browser.

I have face this issue when file name and file type are same.

Below my code

```
$destinationPath = "public/".$destinationPath;
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if($file->isValid() && in_array($extension, $allowedExt)) {
                if (\File::exists($destinationPath.$fileName)) {
                    \File::delete($destinationPath.$fileName);
                }
                if($file->move($destinationPath, $fileName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } return false;
```

Also I have cleared all cache and tried on another PC.

Following commands used to clear the cache.

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan route:clear

Please give me Any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: You have a typo:

    \File::exists($destinationPath..$fileName  Two dots

Comment: Add some debugging in around if (\File::exists($destinationPath..$fileName)) {
                    \File::delete($destinationPath.$fileName);
                } to see if the file is actually being deleted

Comment: did you add debugging to see if the file is actually being deleted? what happens if you visit the file url in your browser?

Comment: is it showing in the public folder on filezilla?

Comment: why are you deleting it, why not just overwrite the file with the same name? Can you give the url where the image is saved?

Comment: did you try overwriting using File::put()?

Comment: ok i am trying. But why not showing me actual image present on server.

Comment: just i have used this put function but not showing me updated file but on server filezilla showing me.

Comment: I have try file::put but issue not solved

Answer (score 1):

I got that solution. Why not reflecting updated image due to on server side maintain cache this is feature provided by Amazon.

Than i have disabled this feature now its working fine.

I hope my solution really helpful to others who's face such that issue.